# Error "**We didn't find any interpreters**" in VS while running a code

Tags: visual-studio, python-2.7, python-3.x, cpython

Why do i get an error message "**We didn't find any interpreters**" when i try to run my code in Visual Studio python ?

Comment: To avoid the question being closed without being answered, please refer to [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 7):

Did you installed a proper Python interpreter? You installed it but Visual Studio can not find it? If yes go to menu View => Other Windows => Python Environments to see following window. Then set correct path of your python.

[image]

For more info see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/python-environments#selecting-and-installing-python-interpreters).